# Getting the Invalid Argument Exception while uploading the file from the local machine to?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

`WebElement se1=Utilities.findElement(SelctFileopt); se1.sendKeys("C:\\Users\\User\\Marquis\\Daily Automation\\from MAster\\Documents\\Signed Contract Pack.pdf");`

I am able to upload the file from my system, but my team member getting this exception, and I have changed the file path but it wont work.

File should be upload to the application

Comment: Is that file closed while team member trying to upload ? And are sure the path is correct ?
There could be many other reason better to provide more detail

Comment: Thank you in advance, let me check with a team member whether a file is closed or not. the suppose to be closed?

Comment: Yes, it should be closed.